# How to fix this?? an error appears while typing npm start in the terminal

Tags: json

npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! path C:\Users\laptop\Desktop\TI\Projects\Flights\flight/package.json

npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 705 while parsing '{

npm ERR! JSON.parse   "homepage": "https://Lahcen-88.githu'

npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.

npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.?

Comment: Please share package.json

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not as serious as it looks! Just run your JSON through a linter or formatter.  Likely a typo or comma in the wrong place.  Hope that helps.